# Return value based on current month

Tags: java

I'm using this Java code to get price based on month start and end date.

```
public int getPrice()
    {
        java.util.Date today = Calendar.getInstance().getTime();

        Calendar aumgc = new GregorianCalendar();
        aumgc.set(Calendar.AUGUST, 8);
        aumgc.set(Calendar.DAY_OF_MONTH, 1);
        java.util.Date augustStart = aumgc.getTime();

        Calendar emgc = new GregorianCalendar();
        emgc.set(Calendar.AUGUST, 8);
        emgc.set(Calendar.DAY_OF_MONTH, 31);
        java.util.Date augustEnd = emgc.getTime();

        Calendar sepmgc = new GregorianCalendar();
        sepmgc.set(Calendar.SEPTEMBER, 9);
        sepmgc.set(Calendar.DAY_OF_MONTH, 1);
        java.util.Date septemberStart = sepmgc.getTime();

        Calendar eomgc = new GregorianCalendar();
        eomgc.set(Calendar.SEPTEMBER, 9);
        eomgc.set(Calendar.DAY_OF_MONTH, 31);
        java.util.Date septemberEnd = eomgc.getTime();

        Calendar ocmgc = new GregorianCalendar();
        ocmgc.set(Calendar.OCTOBER, 10);
        ocmgc.set(Calendar.DAY_OF_MONTH, 1);
        java.util.Date octoberStart = ocmgc.getTime();

        Calendar eocmgc = new GregorianCalendar();
        eocmgc.set(Calendar.OCTOBER, 10);
        eocmgc.set(Calendar.DAY_OF_MONTH, 31);
        java.util.Date octoberEnd = eocmgc.getTime();

        if (!(today.before(augustStart) || today.after(augustEnd)))
        {
            return 30;
        }

        if (!(today.before(septemberStart) || today.after(septemberEnd)))
        {
            return 40;
        }

        if (!(today.before(octoberStart) || today.after(octoberEnd)))
        {
            return 50;
        }
        return 0;

    }
```

As you can see I'm using a lot of code to get the price based on current month. How I can simplify the code and use SQL date?

Is there any already made solution implemented in JVM?

Comment: so using the current moment :  "month is august" => 30, "month is sept" => 4, and month is october" => 50 ?

Comment: How does SQL come into play with your question?

Comment: @azro current - I want this result.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I would suggest to use latest API LocalDateTime from Java 8 to do this king of thing, easily :

```
import java.time.Month;  // Enum use in `switch` statement.

public int getPrice() {
    LocalDateTime now = LocalDateTime.now();   // line 2
    switch (now.getMonth()) {                  // line 3
        case AUGUST:
            return 30;
        case SEPTEMBER:
            return 40;
        case OCTOBER:
            return 50;
        default:
            return 0;
    }
}
// line 2&3 can be reduce in : // switch (LocalDateTime.now().getMonth()){
```

---

This would return the same :

```
public int getPrice() {
     return (LocalDateTime.now().getMonthValue() - 8) * 10 + 30;
}
//or return (LocalDateTime.now().getMonthValue() - 5) * 10;
```

Comment: Thanks! I's just amazed how simple it can be implemented.

Comment: You're welcome, think about accepting the answer if it satisfies you ;)

Comment: Good answer, except: (A) You should be using `ZonedDateTime` as `LocalDateTime` purposely discards time zone information which is likely to be useful. (B) Better to specify expected/desired time zone explicitly rather than rely implicitly on current default: `ZonedDateTime.now( ZoneId.of( "Europe/Sofia" ) )`

Comment: @BasilBourque can you paste complete answer please?

Comment: @PeterPenzov The code by azro is already correct and complete. I would swap out this one line `LocalDateTime now = LocalDateTime.now() ; ` for `ZonedDateTime now = ZonedDateTime.now( ZoneId.of( "Europe/Sofia" ) ) ;` You will get the same result in this case (depending on your default time zone), but makes the code more sensible as there is no need to intentionally discard time zone information. If you do want to use the current default time zone, use: `ZonedDateTime now = ZonedDateTime.now( ZoneId.systemDefault() ) ;` to make your intentions explicit.